# vbs save and close all chrome and word documents

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript, ms-word

I am trying to create a vbscript that clears all my browser data in chrome, then closes all chrome windows.
I am having trouble closing word and outlook.
This it the code that works so far and clears chrome and closes the chrome browser:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "chrome.exe"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "chrome.exe"
WScript.Sleep (1000)
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("^h")
WScript.Sleep (2000)
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ENTER}")
WScript.Sleep (2000)
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ENTER}")
WshShell.AppActivate("Google Chrome")
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8"
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2"
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1"
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16"
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32"
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"

Set objExec = Nothing : Set objShell = Nothing

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Chrome.exe'")

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
oShell.Run "taskkill /im chrome.exe", , True
Next

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("tasklist /fi " & Chr(34) & "imagename eq chrome.exe" & Chr(34))
If Not InStr(1, objExec.StdOut.ReadAll(), "INFO: No tasks", vbTextCompare) Then
objShell.Run "taskkill /f /t /im chrome.exe", 0, True
End If

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'notepad.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

I am trying to close all of the word documents open and save them, basically (control s). I would like all of this to happen in one VBS file so that I can send this to my friends, and they can use it too easily.
I have researched online, but haven't found what I am looking for. 
All the websites that I have looked at have either, only show how to close all documents without saving them or have not shown the process in VBS, instead using VBA or another scripting language.
I would appreciate if someone could help me write my script!

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save and close all documents:

```
'get a handle to the already running Word instance
On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error Goto 0

If Not IsEmpty(wd) Then
  For Each doc In wd.Documents
    doc.Save
    doc.Close
  Next

  wd.Quit
End If
```

For closing all documents without saving change `doc.Save` to `doc.Saved = True`. That basically tells Word "this document was already saved, shut up".

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to do the same thing for notepad?

Comment: No, @equachalk.